# Detect if interface is in promiscuous mode with C

Tags: linux, networking, device, detection, status

I am doing a different tools to check security of linux servers... nothing important and very similar to the tools of chkrootkit. One of the tools I want to do, is like the ifpromisc.c from chkrootkit, that is detect if one of the server interfaces  is in promiscuous mode.

I found an answer on stackoverflow: [howto check a network devices status in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055622/howto-check-a-network-devices-status-in-c)

But after check this solution, I noticed is only for old kernels, because new libpcap doesn't set IFF_PROMISC flag when uses PACKET_MR_PROMISC. I have been looking for other solutions without luck. Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This post might help:
https://lists.archive.carbon60.com/linux/kernel/178148
I haven't been able to find any other way of reaching `dev_set_promiscuity`.
To be honest this is really weird.

Anyways, the post I linked is pretty clear.