# Golang - get promiscuous mode status of network interfaces

Tags: networking, go, interface, promiscuous-mode

I use the following Go code to get some info about the network interfaces. Any suggestions on how I would be able to get the status of promiscuous mode for each interface?

```
type Iface struct {
  Name      string `json:"name"`
  Status    string `json:"status"`
  Multicast bool   `json:"multicast"`
  Broadcast bool   `json:"broadcast"`
}

func (c *InterfacesController) GetInterfaces() {
  interfaces, err := net.Interfaces()

  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
  }

  var ifaceset []Iface
  var ifc Iface

  for _, i := range interfaces {
    ifc.Name = i.Name
    if strings.Contains(i.Flags.String(), "up") {
        ifc.Status = "UP"
    } else {
        ifc.Status = "DOWN"
    }
    if strings.Contains(i.Flags.String(), "multicast") {
        ifc.Multicast = true
    } else {
        ifc.Multicast = false
    }
    if strings.Contains(i.Flags.String(), "broadcast") {
        ifc.Broadcast = true
    } else {
        ifc.Broadcast = false
    }
    ifaceset = append(ifaceset, ifc)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The working environment is Ubuntu, I used the `ifconfig` command and checked each interface details to see if it contains the word `PROMISC`. Something like this:

```
//
// get the interfaces
//
interfaces, err := net.Interfaces()

//
// run the ifconfig command
//
out, err := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", "ifconfig").Output()

var ifc Iface
var ifaceset []Iface

//
// split the output to handle each interface separately
//
var ifaceDetails = strings.Split(string(out), "\n\n")

//
// iterate interfaces
//
for _, i := range interfaces {
    ifc.Name = i.Name
    if strings.Contains(i.Flags.String(), "up") {
    ifc.Status = "UP"
    } else {
        ifc.Status = "DOWN"
    }
    if strings.Contains(i.Flags.String(), "multicast") {
        ifc.Multicast = true
    } else {
        ifc.Multicast = false
    }
    if strings.Contains(i.Flags.String(), "broadcast") {
        ifc.Broadcast = true
    } else {
        ifc.Broadcast = false
    }

    //
    // try to find the word PROMISC to check if it is UP
    //
    for _, ifdetails := range ifaceDetails {
        if strings.Contains(ifdetails, i.Name) {
            if strings.Contains(ifdetails, "PROMISC") {
                ifc.Promisc = true
            } else {
                ifc.Promisc = false
            }

        }
    }
    ifaceset = append(ifaceset, ifc)
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't appear Go has a cross-platform way of checking the PROMISC flag (I can't even find out for sure if such a flag exists for windows.) Here is a way to get it on linux, which I'm guessing you're on:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func GetPromiscuous(i net.Interface) (bool, error) {
    tab, err := syscall.NetlinkRIB(syscall.RTM_GETLINK, syscall.AF_UNSPEC)
    if err != nil {
        return false, os.NewSyscallError("netlinkrib", err)
    }
    msgs, err := syscall.ParseNetlinkMessage(tab)
    if err != nil {
        return false, os.NewSyscallError("parsenetlinkmessage", err)
    }
loop:
    for _, m := range msgs {
        switch m.Header.Type {
        case syscall.NLMSG_DONE:
            break loop
        case syscall.RTM_NEWLINK:
            ifim := (*syscall.IfInfomsg)(unsafe.Pointer(&m.Data[0]))
            if ifim.Index == int32(i.Index) {
                return (ifim.Flags & syscall.IFF_PROMISC) != 0, nil
            }
        }
    }
    return false, os.ErrNotExist
}

func main() {
    ints, err := net.Interfaces()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, i := range ints {
        p, err := GetPromiscuous(i)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(i.Name, p)
    }
}
```

This is based of the [`interfaceTable`](https://golang.org/src/net/interface_linux.go#L16) function in the standard library. It uses [`rtnetlink`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html) to get the flags of the interface. Unless you want to roll your own `syscall.NetlinkRIB` function, this code will always pull the information for every network device and filter out the requested one.

A bit less magical way to get the flag you want is to use cgo and ioctl:

```
package main

/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>

bool is_promisc(char *name) {
    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct ifreq *i = malloc(sizeof *i);

    strncpy((char *)&(i->ifr_name), name, IFNAMSIZ);

    ioctl(s, SIOCGIFFLAGS, i);

    bool p = (i->ifr_flags & IFF_PROMISC) != 0;

    free(i);

    return p;
}
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func GetPromiscuous(i net.Interface) (bool, error) {
    set, err := C.is_promisc(C.CString(i.Name))
    return bool(set), err
}

func main() {
    ints, err := net.Interfaces()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, i := range ints {
        p, err := GetPromiscuous(i)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(i.Name, p)
    }

}
```

A final note is that either way may not always tell you correctly whether an interface is actually in promiscuous mode or not. See [this thread](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/netdev/archive/2002-02/msg00031.html) for more details.

From what I'm reading using the netlink route should work correctly, but another post says we should be checking the promiscuous count. Please let me know if someone knows how to do that, because I can't find how to. The [only stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533297/detect-if-interface-is-in-promiscuous-mode-with-c?rq=1) on the matter has [gone unanswered](https://xkcd.com/979/).

I think either of these methods will work as long as you're not doing any crazy networking stuff (bridge, vlan interfaces, macvtap, etc.) The code definitely works if you use iproute2 tools to turn promisc on and off on an interface.